# What archive formats can Macs open by default?

Tags: macos

I'm a Windows user trying to send something to a Mac user. She can't figure out how to open a zip file, so rather than try to show her how, in this particular case I'd rather just learn what Macs can open by default and make one of those.

What archive formats can be opened by default on a Mac without any additional software?

Comment: @Ramhound Really? There's no standard archive that will work on any mac within the last 5 years? I find that hard to believe. Also, its not my computer so how am I suppose to know the version huh?

Comment: Note that the comment I was replying to there ^ was deleted.

Comment: If an old comment is no longer relevant because it refers to a deleted comment, just delete it rather than added still another comment saying it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macs can both create and open zip files. In fact zip has been the default compressed archive format for Macs for basically the entire life of Mac OS X, so over 15 years.

To decompress a zip archive, just double-click on it in the Finder and it will be decompressed/unarchived and the contents will be placed in a folder of the same name in the same location as the zip archive. If the directory the zip archive is in is not writable by the user, the decompressed contents will be placed on the user’s desktop if I recall correctly (maybe their home directory).

If a Mac user can’t decompress a zip archive, they either are terrifically inept, or the archive was corrupted, or something is wrong with their system. You’re not going to have better luck with any other format.

Comment: Well shoot. I just took them at face value. Maybe they didn't realize they had to download it from google drive first..